# PHP display contents of user uploaded file after submit (preferably without mySQL)

Tags: php, html, file-upload

```
<html>
    <title>TestUploader</title>
    <body>

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) { 
                //display contents of file that was uploaded
            }
        ?>

        <form name="form1" method="POST" action="testupload.php">
            <div>
                Upload A File 
                <br />
                <input type="file" name="UserFile" size="50"/> 
                <br /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit1"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do (and not really finding anything online in terms of examples) is have the user upload a file on their local machine and have PHP read it back to me.

In terms of the actual conditions within my project, it will be a CSV file that I would like to put into an array - but I can't figure out how to do this even with a simple txt file with contents 'hello world'

how i have it constructed in my mind is through POST but i am very novice at php at the moment and do not know if there is a better practice. Could anybody give me guidance or a resource for what i am trying to do? I would prefer to not use MySQL simply because I do not know MySQL yet and am trying to not learn too many things at once and the rest of my project currently does not use it.

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: `echo file_get_contents($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_name']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two good reads to solve your problem

1. To upload File
      http://community.sitepoint.com/t/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-using-php/6270/9
2. Parse it in a way you want
      https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Comment: wow this is pretty much exactly what i was looking for. There are a few commands im not familiar with so it will take me a bit to fully understand what is going on but it would be far less time and better than whatever spaghetti code i could put together. thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code you can try

```
  if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) { 

  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['UserFile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_name']);
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your form needs to send `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and you need to look for `$_FILES`.

have a look at the tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILE["UploadFile"]` at your server. This is not related to MySQL, as MySQL is an RDBMS where you store data. File upload itself is unrelated to MySQL, you can store things in a database though. See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).